# How can i select button with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I select button with same class name.

I have a dropdown menu of class `btn btn-link dropdown-toggle` inside the dropdown i have button with class `btn btn-link`. I am trying to get the inner button inside the dropdown but it selected the dropdoen menu itself.

```
<div class="dropdown overflow show">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="true">Actions<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" s x-placement="bottom-end">
        <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Standard Letter</button></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try to use the following jQuery code to get the inner btn class and trigger the following jQuery but it selected `btn btn-link dropdown-toggle`  instead of dropdown item `<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onkeydown="setTypeStandardLetterChange()" onclick="setTypeStandardLetterChange()">Standard Letter</button>/div>`

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn.btn-link", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#BillingLettersGrid").data("kendoGrid"); grid.refresh();
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid($(this).closest("tr").data("uid"));
    dataItem.FileName = "Standard Letter ";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding adding specificity with the parent div's class of `.dropdown-menu`

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu .btn.btn-link", function (e) {
var grid = $("#BillingLettersGrid").data("kendoGrid"); grid.refresh();
var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid($(this).closest("tr").data("uid"));
dataItem.FileName = "Standard Letter "; })
```

Looks like the div after the second button is closed improperly and the following opening div should be closed.

Comment: it works perfect but one think i have to click it twice to see the changes if you have any idea?

Comment: That's odd. I used your example and commented out what was in the function and added an alert and it worked on first click. 

I also tried with this minor tweak and it worked fine. 
`$('.dropdown-menu').on("click", ".btn.btn-link", function(e) {`
 Did you fix the invalid html? It's possible something else in the jQuery is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.btn.btn-link:not(.dropdown-toggle)` as selector.

I've tried the following code with your HTML, and it worked

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btn.btn-link:not(.dropdown-toggle)", function (e) {
/*
    var grid = $("#BillingLettersGrid").data("kendoGrid"); grid.refresh();
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid($(this).closest("tr").data("uid"));
    dataItem.FileName = "Standard Letter ";
    */
    console.log(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown overflow show">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="true">Actions<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" s x-placement="bottom-end">
        <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Standard Letter</button></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things and avoid having to disqualify the first button from your query, why not give the button you want to query an ID? ID's are required to be unique, so:

```
<button type="button" id="standard-letter" class="btn btn-link">Standard Letter</button>
```

And in your script, `$("#standard-letter").click()` etc.